# c# custom attributes at method level don't override class attributes, is this expected?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an attribute that's at class and method level:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
```

If I set the same attribute with difference params at the method level, the method's attribute does not get priority. Is this expected, or anything that I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: *"the method's attribute does not get priority"* explain this more, what do you mean, what issue is it causing, how are you determining it

Comment: The class attribute's param is used instead of method attribute's param. The specificity looks that does not work.

Comment: I got the answer. It was on my end, the specificity was not hit because one of the parameters forced an exit in the attribute class. Thanks for the quick follow up, I will close this.

Comment: So does it override on the method level or it does not?

Comment: @user3053247 can you explain your solution better? it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that attributes are just marks which does not change anything and the actual behavior is controlled by your self.

The only way to dispatch the behavior of attributes is reflection.

In your reflection logics, if there are attributes found on both class and method level, and you can control it within your code to take the value of the method level one.